# how to generate a unique id for each doctor added to the hospital by the adminintrator in java?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList and need to generate the doctor's id for every doctor added to the hospital by the administrator. so each time a new doctor is added, that doctor will be assigned a particular id in the contructor of the doctor class. 
The problem is that each time i am adding a new doctor, same id is generated for every doctor i.e. id=1, which means id is not been incremented.
Please help me to correct this error.

```
public class Doctor {
private String d_fname;
    private String d_lname;
    private int d_id; 
    private String d_qualification;
    private String d_specialisation;
    private String d_email;
    private int d_contact;
    public int dcount;
    private String d_username;
    private String d_pass;
    private String spass;
    public Doctor(){

    }
    public Doctor(String d_fname, String d_lname, String d_qualification,String d_specialisation,String d_email, int d_contact, int dcount ){
    dcount++;        
    this.d_id=dcount;
    this.d_fname=d_fname;
    this.d_lname=d_lname;
    this.d_qualification=d_qualification;
    this.d_specialisation=d_specialisation; 
    this.d_email=d_email;
    this.d_contact=d_contact; 
    }
    public void setID(int dcount){
    this.d_id=dcount;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String d_fname){
    this.d_fname=d_fname;
    }
    public void setLastName(String d_lname){
    this.d_lname=d_lname;
    }
    public void setQualification(String d_qualification){
    this.d_qualification=d_qualification;
    }
    public void setSpecialisation(String d_specialisation){
    this.d_specialisation=d_specialisation;
    }
    public void setEmail(String d_email){
    this.d_email=d_email;
    }
    public void setContact(int d_contact){
    this.d_contact=d_contact;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
    return this.d_fname;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
    return this.d_lname;
    }
    public int getID(){
    return this.d_id;
    }
    public String getQualification(){
    return this.d_qualification;
    }
     public String getSpecialisation(){
     return this.getSpecialisation();
    } 
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
ParseException, IOException {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//   ArrayList <Patient> patient1 = new ArrayList<Patient>();
ArrayList <Doctor> doctor1 = new ArrayList<Doctor>();

int s=0;
int sh = 0;
int ch = 0;
String pres="";
String d_fname, d_lname,d_qualification, d_specialization, d_email;
int d_contact;
String p_fname, p_lname, p_gender, p_occupation, p_cnic, p_email,p_dob, 
p_bloodGroup,p_maritalStatus;
int p_contact,p_id,dcount=0,pcount=0,d_id = 0, app_no=0;
String date;
do{ 
System.out.println("press 0 to exit");
ch = input.nextInt();
if(ch==0){
System.exit(0);
}
else{
Login login =new Login();
if(login.check()==true ){
if(login.getType()==1)
{
do{
System.out.println("press 1 to add the new doctor's record");
System.out.println("press 2 to delete a doctor's record");
System.out.println("Press 3 to log-out");
ch = input.nextInt();

if(ch==1)
{

System.out.println("enter doctor's first name");
d_fname = input.next();
System.out.println("enter doctor's last name");
d_lname = input.next();

System.out.println("enter doctor's qualification");
d_qualification = input.next();

System.out.println("enter doctor's sepcialization");
d_specialization = input.next();

System.out.println("enter doctor's email address");
d_email = input.next();

System.out.println("enter doctor's contact number");
d_contact = input.nextInt();


Doctor d= new 
Doctor(d_fname,d_lname,d_qualification,d_specialization,d_email,d_contant 
,dcount
);
doctor1.add(d);

System.out.println("id number generated  : " + doctor1.get(d_id).getID()); // 
here i am getting id number 1 each time i am adding a new doctor

}
if(ch==2)
{ 
System.out.println("Which doctor do you want to remove? ");
d_id =input.nextInt();
doctor1.remove(doctor1.get(d_id-1));
System.out.println("Doctor with id number: " + d_id + " is removed 
successfully.");
}
}
while(ch!=3); 
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have some static field in your class, like `numberOfDoctors` that is incremented in your constructor and used to assign a non static id. This way, every instanced class knows how many objects of `Doctor` exist in the program so they can all be assigned a unique id number.

Comment: 1) Create doctor's in a factory method, one that can keep track of number of doctors and increment. 2) Please put in effort to post well-formatted code. Remember that you're asking volunteers to help you, and so you should never make it more difficult to read and understand your code than it has to be.

Comment: Try renaming your question to something that considers the general programming problem you are trying to solve (as opposed to your specific implementations such as _doctors_ and _hospital_). This may make your question easier for others to understand and will also help future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

you need an extra static variable like this

```
private static long IDSeed = 1;
private long d_id;
```

and then in the constructor you do this

```
 d_id = IDSeed;
 IDSeed++;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between (static) class members and instance members:

**static** is for the cases where you don't want to have copy for each instance

**instance** is for the cases where you want separate copy for each instance of object.

The field `dcount` is defined as an instance variable, since you defined it as 'int dcount' (int defaults to 0) it is always 0 for each new object, and gets incremented on the constructor, thus the id always set to 1.

If you want to **just make it work** as you would expect, you should define it as

```
private static final int dcount;
```

Now if you want to improve your code, I'd recommend you (besides a proper indentation) to take a look at the builder pattern [here is a simple example](https://jlordiales.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/). Also you could set the id to the builder from the Main class (to keep it simple) instead of from the Doctor class itself.

Remove all the setters, immutability is your friend, you will thank me later.

And `public int dcount;` is a big nono, use getters instead, you'd be breaking encapsulation otherwise.

Lastly `int` is not thread-safe, use java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger#getAndIncrement() if you ever start spawning threads.